# x64 GNU Assembly issues printing value of register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calculator, gnu

So i am making a simple calculator in x64 GNU assembly and i am having issues printing the value of a register i think i did everything right. This is my first time really doing something with GNU ASM. I came from NASM asm but was not very good at it. The output it letting me enter 2 numbers but not outputting the sum. Ignore the 2 strings unused i will use them after my issue is solved
main.S

```
.data
.lcomm num1, 16
.lcomm num2, 16
.text
.global main
main:
    mov $1,%rax
    mov $1,%rdi
    mov $msg1,%rsi
    mov $18,%rdx
    syscall
    mov $0,%rax
    mov $0,%rdi
    mov $num1,%rsi
    syscall
    mov $1,%rax
    mov $1,%rdi
    mov $msg2,%rsi
    mov $18,%rdx
    syscall
    mov $0,%rax
    mov $0,%rdi
    mov $num2,%rsi
    syscall
    mov $num1,%r8
    mov $num2,%r9
    add %r8,%r9
    add $48,%r9
    mov $1,%rax
    mov $1,%rdi
    mov %r9,%rsi
    mov $2,%rdx
    syscall
    ret
msg1:
    .string "Enter 1st number: "
msg2:
    .string "Enter 2nd number: "
msg3:
    .string "1) Add\n2) Sub\n3) Mul\n4) Div\n> "
msg4:
    .string "Sum of 1st and 2nd number is: "
```

Comment: `mov $num1,%r8` and `mov $num2,%r9` delete the `$` as that means address. Also, change to bytes not qwords. You need to write that back to memory and pass that address to write. The way you do it you will need to subtract the 48 not add it.

Comment: @Jester what do you mean change the bytes and not the qwords and how would i write it back to memory

Comment: `r8` is a 64 bit qword register. Each digit is 1 byte. So you want `r8b`. You write it back to memory by allocating space for it and `mov`-ing back. Or you could reuse one of your inputs. BTW, you should set the length when reading the number. As it is I think you left the 18 from the message printing there.

Comment: @Jester I don't think it's accurate to say `$` means address. After all, `mov $1,%rax` doesn't mean "move the address of 1 to register rax".

Comment: Of course not in the general sense. But for `$num1` it means the address. Generally it just means "immediate operand".